# Bootstrap: 3 columns without margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, margin

I'm working on a website.

I'm trying to create a layout like below using Bootstrap.

[image]

As you can see the elements are inside, but I want to build this single page without margins.

(I mean the picture on the right with no margin)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 sinistra">
      <h4><br><br><br>Uferstrasse 90, 4057 Basel</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 centrale">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 no-float destra">
      <img class="" src="img/simona.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Instead of class="container" add class="container-fluid"

Comment: Bootstrap use negative margins on left and right of first and last inner DIV inside a `.row` and an equal padding on each `.col-*`. What do you mean with "without margins" ? Are you sure that you're not meaning "without padding"? Please provide a jsFiddle with a working example, to allow us to try directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give margin 0 to container div .. Done

Answer (score 1):

Colums like col-md-3 have padding right and padding left .. ovveride this padding and u will get what you want..

Look at this piece of code.

```
.col-md-3 {padding-right:0;padding-left:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "container" class use "container-fluid" class for wrapper div.